# Tomcat 6.x Administration

Tags: configuration, tomcat, tomcat6, administration

With the Administration tool was not ported from Tomcat 5.x to Tomcat 6.x, how do people manage Tomcat configuration?

Are there other 3rd party Admin applications available? Or is all configuration done through editing xml files.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer editing xml files but you can use:

1. [Lambda Probe](http://www.lambdaprobe.org) for some of the information,
2. a JMX client (e.g. JConsole) to play with the various MBeans Tomcat has.

For the record, this message from one of the tomcat developers describes the problems with the admin webapp very well:

http://www.nabble.com/Tomcat-Administrator-tf3415576.html#a9519933

Answer (score 1):

Please checkout MuleSoft Tcat Server for [configuration management](http://www.mulesoft.com/tomcat-configuration-management) across multiple Tomcat servers.

Disclosure: I work for MuleSoft, and would be happy to answer any questions on Tcat Server.